# Safely deleting unused coded: What are all the ways a macro can be called?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to remove some code I believe is unused in a specific Excel VBA Project. I think I've checked all the places that macros can be hiding, but I want to be absolutely sure the workbook won't try to a call certain sub after I delete it. Is my checklist complete?

```
1. The code itself, called by other subroutines
2. Assigned to a shape on a worksheet
3. In a worksheet cell as a user defined function
4. Called by the XML of a custom ribbon
```

Comment: Make a copy of the workbook. Delete something then run the macro to see if it works. If not, go back to the copy and try again. If it works, save the result to a new file name and repeat.

Comment: All the code is in VBE - just check all the sheets and modules to see if they are needed. There are many more ways code can be called outside of your list (events) but regardless of how it's called, it's all in VBE for your review...

Comment: @urdearboy I think that they have code in the VBE that they want to remove, but they need to confirm that it’s not called from the excel model anywhere.  Searching the VBE will not tell you that.

Comment: Seems like looking at what the code does would give you a good idea of how/when/why it's being called?

Comment: No that’s really not how excel works.  The code is in the VBE projects, but it can be called from many places in the excel model itself.  There no way that I know of to search that in one place.

Comment: @CindyMeister nails it again - save a copy, delete the "maybe-dead" code, see if anything broke, rinse & repeat. And now you know to put a comment or otherwise annotate public procedures that are invoked from a worksheet.

Comment: This is a very valid and legitimate question, I do not know why people are downvoting it.  But I suspect it’s because they do not understand how hard this is to do.  For instance, the suggestion made by @CindyMeister can be helpful, but it is far from a definitive test.

Comment: @RBarryYoung "what are all the dozens of different ways an Excel worksheet might break if I delete a public procedure in a VBA project" is not a good question to ask on this site, no.

Comment: This question meets the guidelines for this site.  “What are all the ways a VBA method can be called from Excel?” is a perfectly valid question for this site.

Comment: Damn, I got told off by rubberduck. It may not be a legitimate question, but cleaning up unused code without breaking production is a legitimate task. We've all seen what those trash heaps can look like.

Comment: I think it's a reasonable question which would be useful to anyone just coming into VBA or who has had to inherit an existing project from a colleague and is trying to figure out how it all works.

Comment: @TimWilliams fine, I've put in the 3rd reopen vote. Question strikes me as something that can only be answered with an ever-growing list of Excel features, but eh whatever, I've cast my last vote-to-close on this site.

Comment: @PBeezy It actually *is* a perfectly legitimate question for this site.  The fact that the vendor, Microsoft, has provided neither a definitive list, nor a sufficient tool so that we can give an adequate answer is *not* the fault of the question or the questioner.

Answer (score -1):

Also:

- Called from a VBA Form
- Called from an embedded com Control
- Called from an Active X control
- Called from the shortcut menu
- Called from one of the 6 different types of addins
- Functions called by conditional formatting
- Called from the ribbons extensions menu (compatibility for the previous menu customization facility)

Sorry, I cannot remember the correct term/name for that last one.

They may be others as well.  It’s pretty hard to definitively track down all of the possibilities.